# How to stop bootstrap model close when click outside of model in angular 4

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I am using angular 4, I want to not to close model when I click outside of model. I am using below code:

```
<div id="confirmTaskDelete" class="modal fade" [config]="
{backdrop: 'static',  keyboard: false}" role="dialog" 
style="z-index:999999">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-width">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-
dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #closeTaskPopUpbtn>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title modal-title-
color">Are you sure you want to delete this task?</h3>
                <div class="text-p" style="margin-
top:53px;margin-bottom:35px;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-
primary" id="deletebtn" data-dismiss="modal" >OK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-
primary" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it is giving me error:

> Error: Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of
>   'div'.

Comment: can you add  your code in stackblitz

Comment: did you tried ` data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"` properties on div. this might help you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-eknkjo?file=app/app.component.html - here is solution to your problem!

Comment: Thanks @changulpaye for your attentions. But instead of button, i am using <a> tag.
It is working fine for button but not for <a> </a>  tag

Answer (score 2):

You can use **data-keyboard** and **data-backdrop**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="exampleModal" class="modal fade"  role="dialog" style="z-index:999999" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-width">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" #closeTaskPopUpbtn>
                    <span aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">×</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title modal-title-
                   color">Are you sure you want to delete this task?</h3>
                <div class="text-p" style="margin-top:53px;margin-bottom:35px;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-
                   primary" id="deletebtn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-
                 primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-5dgghk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)  demo

Comment: I glad to help you.. If this answer helpful to you then please approve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add directive and template ref variable inside div tag

```
  <div  id="confirmTaskDelete" class="modal fade"  
        bsModal #confirmTaskDelete="bs-modal" //<===========here you should be add this
        [config]="{backdrop: 'static',  keyboard: false}" 
        role="dialog" 
        style="z-index:999999">
```

Rest of html is working fine..